# How to clear the provider cache to use with useFactory in Angular 7

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular7

I am creating elements on the fly and one of these elements is using an `@Inject` token that resolves to a factory.

The problem is that the factory instance is cached on a node index. Once my element disappear from the view, and comes back, I expect to get a call to my factory function; but I do not. Instead I get a cached version of this factory instance.

[image]

How to ensure that the cache is not used after the object has disappeared from the view?

Basically, when my `@Component` constructor is called, I expect a brand new service. Not a cached service.

```
@Inject(FORM_GROUP_MANAGER_SERVICE)
private formGroupManagerService: FormGroupManagerServiceImpl
```

```
{
    provide: FORM_GROUP_MANAGER_SERVICE,
    useFactory: (structureControlService, createTonicControlFactory, parent) => new FormGroupManagerService(
        structureControlService,
        createTonicControlFactory,
        parent
    ),
    deps: [StructureControlService, FORM_GROUP_MANAGER_SERVICE_CREATE_CONTROL, [new Optional(), FormGroupManagerService]]
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a feature request for this [in the angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18015), but for now I can think of 2 approaches:

- Directly inject the factory method instead of the resolved instance of it. This way a client of it could resolve instances by itself, making it responsable for the lifetime of the resolved object as well.
- Register the factory provider at *directive/component level* as [in this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnxgbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Indeed, I opted for the first option. The bug does not talk about caching, but it would fix the problem if I were to get a brand new service every time.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing something similar where I am providing the request object to my application using useValue but I can see that it is holding on to old versions.  I wrote a simple console log with a random number in one of the functions that run and proceed to refresh the application a few times.

Over time multiple versions of the same function get called.  Registering at the component level doesn't seem like a good idea, and I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by "Directly inject the factory method" because I thought I was doing that already.